Rviz shows pixels for the camera output
I want to visualize KUKA iiwa robot with the kinect camera sensor in rviz. The visualization shows pixels for the entire perspective of the camera (as shown in image attached). When the robot moves the pixels in the background changes as well. Hence I am feeling it's a perspective from camera. How can I eliminate that and just show robot?
